# Pop a key value along with entire path from a python nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary as below. I need to pop a key and its value from the dictionary with the whole path for that key in the nested dictionary and put it in a list.

```
a={'aa': {'1': {'bb':{'2': {'cc' : ['xx', 'yy']},
                      '3': {'dd' : ['zz', 'yy']}}},
        '11': {'bbb':{'22': {'cc': ['xxx', 'yyy']},
                      '33': {'dd' : ['zz', 'yy']}}}}}
```

I am looking for a list with popped valued like this

```
lis = [{'aa': {'1': {'bb':{'3': {'dd' : ['zz', 'yy']},  {'aa': {'11': {'bbb':{'33': {'dd' : ['zz', 'yy']}]
```

My code is as below. It pops the value from the ditionary but not able to store it in a list. Is there a way that I could store the popped value with its entire path in a list  as above?

```
def delete_keys_from_dict(dict_del, lst_keys):
    for k in lst_keys:
        try:
            dict_del.pop(k)
        except KeyError:
            pass
    for v in dict_del.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            delete_keys_from_dict(v, lst_keys)    
    return dict_del    

delete_keys_from_dict(a, ['dd'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You are looking for poped values .You can add the poped value to a list while removing from dictionary.

```
  a={'aa': {'1': {'bb':{'2': {'cc' : ['xx', 'yy']},
                          '3': {'dd' : ['zz', 'yy']}}},
            '11': {'bbb':{'22': {'cc': ['xxx', 'yyy']},
                          '33': {'dd' : ['zz', 'yy']}}}}}

    def delete_keys_from_dict(dict_del, lst_keys,res=[]):
        for k in lst_keys:
            try:
                res.append((k,dict_del.pop(k)))
            except KeyError:
                pass
        for v in dict_del.values():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                delete_keys_from_dict(v, lst_keys)    
        return dict_del,res

    result = delete_keys_from_dict(a, ['dd'])
    print('Updated Dictionary : ' + str(result[0]))

    print('Deleted  : ' + str(result[1]))
```

OutputL

```
Updated Dictionary : {'aa': {'1': {'bb': {'3': {}, '2': {'cc': ['xx', 'yy']}}}, '11': {'bbb': {'22': {'cc': ['xxx', 'yyy']}, '33': {}}}}}

Deleted  : [('dd', ['zz', 'yy']), ('dd', ['zz', 'yy'])]
```

Comment: You shouldn't be setting the default value to a list, multiple calls to `delete_keys_from_dict` will return wrong results.

Comment: @himanshu Is there a way to get the entire path of the deleted keys as like {'aa': {'1': {'bb':{'3': {'dd' : ['zz', 'yy']} ?